# Lenovo ThinkPad L570 20J8 - Core i5

Tags: 16.04, drivers, lenovo

At the beginning of 2018 there was issues with an Intel driver and Canonical, where an Ubuntu installation would erase BIOS of Lenovo machines.

Now I have a Lenovo Thinkpad L570 I would like to install Ubuntu mini 16.04 LTS on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD, my question is has the bug been fixed in this version? Is there an official statement from Canonical somewhere that says that versions this and that is safe to use for Lenovo machines again?

Comment: My apologies, but I'm unaware of the bug of which you speak. Do you have a source that you could [edit] into your post?

Comment: Probably this: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-17-10-bios-bug/